# css : display: table (FF works well. Not working with Chrome and Edge)

Tags: html, css

I am having the following problem on Chrome and MS Edge.

My html & CSS code:

```css
section.content-background {
  width: 655px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #bebebe;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
section.content-firstground {
  width: 645px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ececec;
  display: table;
}
div.personal-info-image {
  width: 170px;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  background-color: #FFF;
  float: left;
  background-image: url(../_images/person-info-image.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
div.content-input {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #424242;
}
```

```html
<section class="content-background">
  <section class="content-firstground">

    <div class="personal-info-image">
    </div>

    <div class="content-input">
    </div>

    <div class="content-input">
    </div>
    <div class="content-input">
    </div>
    <div class="content-input">
    </div>

  </section>
</section>
```

The div.personal-info-image is not appearing on Chrome and MS Edge.

Any help to solve this?

Comment: Its not that is not appearing but you are using wrong css. You put width fixed and height with %. Anyway the answer below fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome doesn't like height being 100% on the `.personal-info-image` class. If you give this an absolute height, the image will display.

For example: `height:204px;`

```
div.personal-info-image{
  width: 170px; 
  height:204px; 
  background-color: #FFF; 
  float: left;   
  background-image:url(http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/onesport/cps/800/cpsprodpb/4039/production/_89214461_vardy-mahrez.jpg); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-position: center;
}
```

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/h9m40f9L/

Comment: Yes, it would work. However I need it to be 100% on height to follow the number of inputs on the right

Comment: In which case, you may need to use JavaScript to count the number of rows on right to work out what the height should be. Either that, or it's a complete refactor of your markup.